# Integrate Kaltura with Salesforce

Tags: api

I would like to integrate [Kaltura](http://corp.kaltura.com/) with Slaesforce. Doing so I would like to sync data from Kaltura to Salesforce, i.e., want to feed data back to Salesforce as far as what the (Salesforce Community) User did on the Kaltura side. What videos they watched, and other statistical data back into Salesforce.

Haven't got much to start with and was hoping if there are any open APIs which I could invoke from Salesforce and pull data eventually. That being said, would also like to know which parameters to feed while invoking the service call.

Best Regards

Comment: Do you mind clarifying what exactly you are looking for?
Are you looking for documentation, or experienced actual practical help?

Because here are the Kaltura resources online:
http://corp.kaltura.com/Products/Kaltura-API
http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/testmeDoc/index.php?page=inout

Comment: @canyoucatchme I'm actually looking for practical help. Wanted to check if anyone in the community had prior experience on Kaltura-Salesforce integration. I was wondering if there any APIs available to use and make API callouts in Salesforce, which apparently pull data according to the request type made.